# What are some potential reasons for no significant difference between Random Feature Selection and Automatic Feature Selection?

Tags: classification, feature-selection

[image: Experimental results]

Basic info abut the experiment:

- Binary classification of exons
- 10 fold cross validation
- 1200 features of exons are ranked by Fisher Score, Relief and Gini Index feature selection algorithms
- 1-nearest neighbor classifier is applied to the ranked list of features.

  - The classifier is trained on 1 best feature, on 2 best features, on 3 best features, ...

There is no significant difference between Random Feature Selection and Automatic Feature Selection.

John, Kohavi, and Pfleger defines the following categories of features:
[image: John, Kohavi, and Pfleger defines the following categories of features]

What are some potential reasons for no significant difference between Random Feature Selection and Automatic Feature Selection? Does that mean that all of 1200 features are strongly relevant?

Reference:
G. H. John, R. Kohavi, and P. Pfleger. Irrelevant features and the subset
selection problem. In Machine Learning: Proceedings of the Eleventh Inter-
national Conference. Morgan Kaufmann, 1994.

Comment: It appears that you are using improper accuracy scoring rules.  See [this](http://fharrell.com/post/class-damage).

Comment: I tried to use AUROC. AUROC is a continuous accuracy score. I conducted a new experiment with the help of 3NN classifier. I obtained approximately the same results. So there is no significant difference between Random Feature Selection and Automatic Feature Selection. 

Could you please confirm that AUROC is a proper accuracy scoring rule for my case? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: AUROC is semi-proper.  It does not give adequate weight to extreme predictions that are right.  So it lacks statistical power.  A proper score would be the Brier score or the logarithmic scoring rules (which is a function of the log-likelihood).  Any function of the log-likelihood, including pseudo $R^2$ will provide maximum statistical utility.

Comment: Your feature selection might be too noisy?

Comment: @FrankHarrell 
I calculated  Brier score. Here is a  result: https://prnt.sc/jnbf5p
There is still no significant difference between Random Feature Selection and Automatic Feature Selection. Do you have an idea of some potential reasons for that?

Comment: I see Fisher dominating random up until about 500 features (smaller Brier is better).  In general feature selection is not a great idea.  It's usually better to concentrate on predictive discrimination using penalization on all predictors.  I also recommend you get bootstrap confidence intervals for the ranks of features in terms of predictive discrimination, as described [here](http://fharrell.com/doc/bbr.pdf) in Chapter 20.